# Manual form validation jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do some manual form validation in jQuery just to get a hang of it.
I know there are plugins that do this but this is not the point.

This is my code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
//amount of input fields we need this for activation of button
var amount = $('.form-group').length;

  //blur checks when you leave an input field
$('.form-group input').blur( function() {
    //if the input is empty put red bg color
    if( !$(this).val() ) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    }
     //if field is filled in bg is white and amount -1.
     //once amount is 1 we know fields are filled in
        if( $(this).val() ) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
        amount = amount - 1;
        if(amount === 1 && $('#tos').prop('checked') ) {
          //code to remove the attribute disabled
          $('button').removeAttr("disabled")
          $('button').html("Send")

            }
        }

    });
});
```

It breaks on following line:

```
if(amount === 1 && $('#tos').prop('checked') )
```

both work fine if I write them seperate but when I try to use the && operator doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What's the error that you see?

Comment: This is the big picture,
http://i.gyazo.com/e17c6b0f6e6432399aad336fc44bd348.png
No error, just does not execute.

If I remove the checkbox it works fine, if I remove the amount counter it works but only after I fill in 1 field, I think the code doesnt execute if I dont fill in anything because of blur and since it is the last thing you do it doesnt execute the code anymore. I guess I need to figure out how to execute the code even if a mousepress is done?

Comment: What are you doing with `amount = amount - 1;`? I bet it's something that is preventing you to validate the condition. Try to debug it!

Answer (score 2):

try using additional grouping

```
if((amount === 1) && $('#tos').prop('checked') )
```

According to the [operator precedence table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) the `===` has higher precedence than the `&&` so your code should not need the additional grouping though.. Hmz.

Comment: This is the big picture,
http://i.gyazo.com/e17c6b0f6e6432399aad336fc44bd348.png
No error, just does not execute.

Comment: @koenpeters, It doesn't matter to group it should work without grouping.